# How to set which control displays top when they overlap?

Tags: ios

I have a UIView and a toolbar. I want the toolbar to always stay on top when they overlap. Is there a property, like z-index in html stylesheet, for iphone controls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call bringSubviewToFront for the control you want to be on the top.

```
[somesuperview bringSubviewToFront:yourtoolbar];
```